# Angular2 http get issue returning a string

Tags: angular, get, xmlhttprequest, angular2-services

I have a simple Flask app running that returns a string
[image]

and my Angular2 code has been cobbled together from various tutorials that I've seen online
webservices.services.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {
  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router,private _jsonp: JsonpModule) { }

 public getDataFromBackend() {//
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/getstuff')
    .map(data=>{
        data.json();
        console.log(data.json());
        return data.json();
    })
  }
}
```

App.Component.ts

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './webservices/webservices.services';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  providers: [WebService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http,  private webservice: WebService, private router: Router) { }
  title: string = 'My first angular2-google-maps project';
  lat: number = 45.478418;
  lng: number = -122.209007;
  msgBackend: string = "";
  public ngOnInit(){

  }
 public getData(){
    this.webservice.getDataFromBackend()
      .subscribe(
      (data) => this.handleData(data),

      () => console.log('Write to console output')

      );
  }

    private handleData(data: Response) {
    if (data.status === 200) {
      let receivedData = data.json();
      console.log(receivedData);
      this.msgBackend= receivedData;
      return this.msgBackend;
    }


  }





}
```

So when my app runs, it does hit the Flask app and returns a 200. Also, the console does indeed write "Write to console output". I also tried adding an observable Observable but that didn't work. I think I'm just not grasping Angular2 http and async stuff.

EDIT: console.log(receivedData);
why isn't it going to the console?

Comment: What's the issue? You never mentioned it.

Comment: console.log(receivedData); Why isn't it going to the console?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned, since this is not JSON, but string, use `response.text()` instead, like so:

```ts
public getDataFromBackend() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/getstuff')
   .map(response => response.text())
}
```

and in component:

```ts
public getData(){
  this.webservice.getDataFromBackend()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.handleData(data),
  });
}
```

And in your `handleData`, we are no longer dealing with `Response`, but the data is just simply a string at that point:

```ts
private handleData(data: string) {
  console.log(data);
  this.msgBackend= data;
}
```

Comment: Getting a `Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: For me it worked with the responseType: 'text' (see my answer)

Answer (score 5):

The answer with the most upvotes did not work for me, sadly the suggested answer from the angular manual required a @ts-ignore but still works fine.

```
// @ts-ignore
return this.http.get<string>('my-api-url', {responseType: 'text'});
```

From https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response :

```
// this works 
 client.get('/foo', {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: Thanks the  {responseType: 'text'}) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning text and not actual json use `response.text()`

Update your `getDataFromBackend` to this, returning the text, not the response.

```
public getDataFromBackend() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/getstuff')
    .map(response =>{
        response.json();
        return response.body;
    })
  }
```

Then update `handleData` to:

```
private handleData(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
    this.msgBackend= data;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...Whatever the Visual Studio Code equivalence of intellisense is doesn't like response.Body.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself.  Based on the observed behavior the httpclient is expecting a Json object and not a simple string.  I was seeing a parsing error when I returned the simple string.

The solution I used was to wrap the result in the back-end into a Json object

```
    return this.http.get(url, {headers:header}).pipe(
        map(this.handleGetResponse),
        catchError(this.handleResponseError));

    private handleGetResponse(res: any): string {
    var returnValue: string = res.result;
    return returnValue;
    }
```